# Why does MySql.NET driver need .NET 2.0 for a .NET 4 application

Tags: mysql-connector

I am rolling out a WPF application which uses Entity Framework but also has MySqlConnection connections.

On Windows 7 the rollout is fine with just .net 4 installed, but on SOME older hardware running XP I have run into difficulties.

The symptoms are varied.

1. I install the driver and Entity Framework operations are successful but MySqlCommands fail - the event viewer either (depending on which machine) shows a FileNotFound Exception or it shows an exception relating to the .NET 2 optimiser.
2. I install the driver and nothing works - the error is that the driver failed to load.
3. I attempt to load the driver but the install complains that either .net 4 or .net 2 needs to be installed even though .net 4 is present.

One XP workstation out of the half dozen or so I have tried worked perfectly first time - what I noticed on this machine was that .net versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.5 and 4 were all present before I performed the MySql connector installation.

I am going to try uninstalling .net 4, reinstall .net 2 and then install the MySql connectors to see if that resolves the problem, but if I am honest I am hacking away at this without really knowing what the underlying issue is.

Can anyone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we found was that those workstations that had .NET 4 'Extended' preinstalled, and those that had a full 2, 3.5, 4.0 history of .NET preinstalled worked without a problem.

The workstations that only had .NET 4 'Client Profile' installed were not supported by, or did not support, the MySqlConnector.  We found this to be true for a number of different MySqlConnector versions.